# Find the sum of the digits in the number 100! (My while loop would not stop)

Tags: java, biginteger, factorial

I've been trying to solve [Problem 20](https://projecteuler.net/problem=20) in Project Euler:

> n! means n  (n  1)  ...  3 * 2 * 1
>   For example, 10! = 10 * 9  ...  3 * 2 * 1 = 3628800,
>   and the sum of the digits in the number 10! is 3 + 6 + 2 + 8 + 8 + 0 + 0 = 27.
>   Find the sum of the digits in the number 100!

This is what I came up with so far. I already got the correct answer (which was 648) with this code, but I got a bit OC, because my code is an infinite loop. After the result became 0 inside the while loop, it just wouldn't stop. Can anybody help me fix this?

```
public static BigInteger problem20(int max){
    BigInteger sum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    BigInteger currentNum = BigInteger.valueOf(0);

    for(long i = 1; i<=max; i++){
        result  = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        //System.out.println(result);
    }

    while (!result.equals(0)) {
        sum = sum.add(result.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10)));
        result = result.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
        System.out.println(sum + " "+ result);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
while (!result.equals(0))
```

`result` is a `BigInteger`, which will never be equal to an `Integer`. Try using

```
while (!result.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
```

Comment: OMG! I knew it has to be somewhere along those lines! >_< Thank you so much! <3

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use `while (fact.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0)`.

I recommend you to use `BigInteger.ZERO`, `BigInteger.ONE` and `BigInteger.TEN` where it is possible.

Example:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class P20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getSum(100));
    }

    private static long getSum(int n) {
        BigInteger fact = BigInteger.ONE;
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        long sum = 0;
        while (fact.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) > 0) {
            sum += fact.mod(BigInteger.TEN).longValue();
            fact = fact.divide(BigInteger.TEN);
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

It takes **4 ms**.

It can be improved using the following observation:

- the sum is not influenced by zeros => you don't need to multiply by 10 and 100 and instead of 20, 30, ... it's enough to use 2, 3, ... . Of course, you can generalize this rule using the following fact `5*k * 2*j` is divisible by `10`.

Answer (score 0):

Please modify your code to :

```
    while (!result.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(0))) {
        sum = sum.add(result.mod(BigInteger.valueOf(10)));
        result = result.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(10));
        System.out.println(sum + " "+ result);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing the same.In this, the complexity to compute the sum is O(1).

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
        for(int i=2;i<=5;i++){
            b = b.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
        }
        //System.out.println(b);
```

*computing the sum below*

```
final BigInteger NINE = BigInteger.valueOf(9);
            if(b == BigInteger.ZERO){
                System.out.println(b);
            }else if(b.mod(NINE) == BigInteger.ZERO){
                System.out.println(NINE);
            }else{
                System.out.println(b.mod(NINE));
            }

        }`
}
```